# relative border-size on pseudo-elements is wonky in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, border, pseudo-element

I'm using 'CSS triangles' (different border sizes/colours on a pseudo-element) to give an arrow-like appearance to elements on a webpage. I size everything using relative units, so that things scale as they should when the user agent stylesheet has a non-default font size.

```
.arrow {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.arrow:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* all positioning/size units should line up with the
                               outside of the border */
    top: 0; /* align triangle with top of container */
    left: 100%; /* push triangle to right of container */
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(255, 66, 0, 0); /* transparent */
    border-width: 0.75em; 
    border-left-color: rgb(255, 66, 0); /* here's where the triangle is created */
}
```

All works well, except that in Chrome (currently using version 23) when I zoom in and out, the border size seems to be calculated incorrectly -- the border grows/shrinks much faster than the rest of the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/hXN9p/

If I use absolute units, the problem goes away (but I don't want to use absolute units):

http://jsfiddle.net/hXN9p/2/

Other Webkit browsers (i.e., Safari) don't exhibit this behaviour, and even IE8 doesn't have trouble.

**UPDATE**: I've managed to simplify the case; it has nothing to do with pseudo-elements and everything to do with the way Chrome calculates border-width with relative units. Here's an example; when you zoom in and out, the two elements stop being the same height:

http://jsfiddle.net/W2SdF/